# How to set unlimited max connections for a TCP listening socket on Linux?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I do not know how to set the maximum connections to unlimited.

I tried to set the max connections to **0**, but I don't know if it's unlimited.

Does 0 mean unlimited?

```
listen(serverSocket, maxConnections)
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for [SOMAXCONN](https://linux.die.net/man/3/listen). That may not be truly unlimited, but it's as many as available anyway.

Comment: the 2nd parameter of listen is [backlog](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html). The server can handle more connection that this parameter. It just need to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listen`'s man page states the following:

> The behavior of the backlog argument on TCP sockets changed with Linux
> 2.2.  Now it specifies the queue length for completely established sockets waiting to be accepted, instead of the number of incomplete
> connection requests.  The maximum length of the queue for incomplete
> sockets can be set using      /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog.
> When syncookies are enabled there is no logical maximum length and
> this setting is ignored.  See tcp(7) for more information.
>
> If the backlog argument is greater than the value in
> /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn, then it is silently capped to that
> value.  Since Linux 5.4, the default in this file is 4096; in earlier
> kernels, the default value is 128. In kernels before 2.4.25, this
> limit was a hard coded value, SOMAXCONN, with the value 128.

`SOMACONN` is defined in `<sys/socket.h>`.

And as @Jerry commented: *"That may not be truly unlimited, but it's as many as available anyway."*